# Restrict rows in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table `IdentifySlot` with data like this:

```
Cname   TotalEmpty
------------------
CName1      4
CName2      3
CName3      1
CName4      7
CName5     30
CName6     36
```

and I also have an `ActualSlot` table:

```
CName   AppDate       RankNumber
--------------------------------
CName1  05/01/2018        1
CName1  05/01/2018        2
CName1  16/02/2018        3
CName2  05/01/2018        1
CName2  19/01/2018        2
CName2  17/02/2018        3
CName2  18/02/2018        4
CName2  19/02/2018        5
CName2  20/02/2018        6
CName3  15/01/2018        1
CName3  16/02/2018        2
CName3  21/02/2018        3
CName4  12/01/2018        1
CName4  02/02/2018        2
CName5  14/01/2018        1
CName5  02/02/2018        2
CName5  22/02/2018        3
CName6  26/01/2018        1
CName6  09/02/2018        2
CName6  09/02/2018        3
Cname+n date+n            n
```

I would like to restrict the rows like this: I want to use the `TotalEmpty` column in the `IdentifySlot` table and restrict rows in the `ActualSlot` table only to

- 4 rows for CName1,
- 3 rows for CName2
- 1 rows for CName3
- 7 rows for CName4 and
- 30 rows for CName5 and so on...

from the `ActualSlot` table.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT TOP (b.TotalEmpty) 
    ApptID, CName, AppDate
FROM
    ActualSlot  a 
LEFT JOIN
    ActualSlot b ON a.CName = b.CName
WHERE
    b.CName = 'CName1'

UNION

SELECT TOP (b.TotalEmpty) 
    ApptID, CName, AppDate
FROM 
    ActualSlot  a 
LEFT JOIN 
    ActualSlot b ON a.CName = b.CName
WHERE 
    b.CName = 'CName2'

UNION

SELECT TOP (b.TotalEmpty) 
    ApptID, CName, AppDate
FROM 
    ActualSlot  a 
LEFT JOIN 
    ActualSlot b ON a.CName = b.CName
WHERE 
    b.CName = 'CName3'
```

but it does not work. I think I need to write a stored procedure to loop the 'CNames' one at a time instead of unions... any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: You could use a cross apply or something like that if you want. e.g. `SELECT b.* FROM IdentifySlot AS a CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (a.TotalEmpty) * FROM ActualSlot AS b WHERE b.CName = a.CName) AS b;`

Comment: is ranknumber a column in actualslot table?

Comment: yes ranknumber is a column

Answer (score 0):

You may use ROW_NUMBER in a sub query like this:

```
SELECT CName, AppDate, RankNumber FROM (
    ApptID,
    CName,
    AppDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cname ORDER BY AppDate) RankNumber
    From ActualSlot
) a 
Left Join ActualSlot b on a.CName= b.CName
WHERE  b.CName = 'CName1'
AND RankNumber <= b.TotalEmpty
UNION ALL
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a result like this?

```
SELECT b.totalempty,
       a.cname,
       a.appdate
  FROM actualslot  a 
 INNER JOIN identifyslot b 
    ON a.cname = b.cname
   AND a.ranknumber <= b.totalempty
```

Result

```
totalempty  cname   appdate     ranknumber
4           CName1  2018-01-05  1
4           CName1  2018-01-05  2
4           CName1  2018-02-16  3
3           CName2  2018-01-05  1
3           CName2  2018-01-19  2
3           CName2  2018-02-17  3
1           CName3  2018-01-15  1
7           CName4  2018-01-12  1
7           CName4  2018-02-02  2
30          CName5  2018-01-14  1
30          CName5  2018-02-02  2
30          CName5  2018-02-22  3
36          CName6  2018-01-26  1
36          CName6  2018-02-09  2
36          CName6  2018-02-09  3
```